# Defaults for Backbone views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this annoying problem and I get the feeling it's because we can't use defaults for Backbone Views as we would with Backbone Models. My goal was to use defaults with a Backbone View and then override them with options passed to the initialize function as desired. The problem that I am having is that when I call this.collection Backbone doesn't match this with this.defaults.collection, as I would expect. I get a null point exception when I call this.collection in the initialize function even though I assigned collection in defaults.

Perhaps what I need is this call in my initialize function:

```
  this.options = _.extend(this.defaults, this.options);
```

however, in this case, then defaults is not doing anything special. this.defaults could be called this.cholo. I guess I am wondering why defaults/attributes won't act the same as Backbone Models.

I have the following code:

```
var IndexView = Backbone.View.extend({

                el: '#main-div-id',

                defaults: function(){
                    return{
                        model: null,
                        collection: collections.users,  
                        childViews:{
                            childLoginView: null,
                            childRegisteredUsersView: null
                        }
                    }
                },

                events: {
                    'click #loginAsGuest': 'onLoginAsGuest',
                    'click #accountRecoveryId': 'onAccountRecovery'
                },

                initialize: function (opts) {

                    this.options = Backbone.setViewOptions(this, opts);
                    Backbone.assignModelOptions(this,this.options);

                    _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'onFetchSuccess', 'onFetchFailure');

                    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add remove reset', this.render);  //this.collection is not defined here

                    this.collection.fetch({ //null pointer here, this.collection is not defined
                        success: this.onFetchSuccess.bind(this),
                        error: this.onFetchFailure.bind(this)
                    });
                },

                render: function () {
                  //removed code because it's extraneous for this example

                },

                onFetchSuccess: function () {},

                onFetchFailure: function () {}
            },
            { //classProperties

                givenName: '@IndexView'
            });
```

...by the way, in order to make events different for each instance of the view, should I turn events into a function like defaults?

Comment: Note that [`_.extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) modifies its first argument so you don't want to `_.extend(this.defaults, ...)` since `defaults` is going to be on the prototype and thus shared by all instances. You'd want to `_.extend({ }, this.defaults, ...)` instead.

Comment: thanks I was literally just wondering why the first argument needed to be an empty object. sideeffects in full effect, all the way baby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is really nothing special about the `defaults` literal within a `Backbone.Model`. If you take a look at the [Backbone source](http://backbonejs.org/backbone.js), they're essentially doing this within the model constructor

```
Backbone.Model = function( attributes, options ) {
  // simplified for example
  var attrs = _.defaults( {}, attributes, this.defaults );
  this.set( attrs, options );
};
```

You can take the exact same approach when setting up your views

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend( {
  options: {
    // your options
  },

  initialize: function( options ) {
    this.options = _.defaults( {}, options, this.options );
  }
} );
```

If you would like to define your options as a function so it's evaluated at runtime, you can use the following

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend( {
  options: function() {
    // your options
  },

  initialize: function( options ) {
    this.options = _.defaults( {}, options, _.result(this, 'options') );
  }
} );
```

To answer your other question about different events per instance, yes you can either define it as a function and include the logic within that function OR simply pass `events: { ... }` as an option when instantiating the view.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yeah thanks, and also the Backbone source assigns this.x for each of the options.x properties, so that mapping is an important piece of the puzzle

Comment: Well not exactly, it only does this for a defined set of options. For example, in a `Backbone.View`, it'll only do it for `'model', 'collection', 'el', 'id', 'attributes', 'className', 'tagName', 'events'`. If you were to pass `foo: 'bar'` as an option, it would NOT be available as `this.foo` within the view.

Comment: is this a typo: `var attrs = _.defaults( {}, attrs, this.defaults );` ? i think you meant to pass `attributes`: `var attrs = _.defaults( {}, attributes, this.defaults );`

Comment: @EliranMalka yes that's a typo, I've made an edit to my answer. Thank you for pointing that out.